# math abstraction of out product with condition

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication

I have two arrays to compare. Label True/False from a comparing b :

```
a=c(2.9,3.7,3.8, 2.7,3.3, 3.9) and b=c(18,21, 30 ,21, 17, 27)
```

And I use

```
 compare=outer(a,a,'>=') & outer(b,b,'>=') # Return True if a[1]>=a[2] and b[1]>=b[2], etc
```

to get a boolean matrix:

```
  [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]

    [1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
    [2,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
    [3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
    [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
    [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
    [6,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

How can I write this compare procedure into math way. It is a out product Is it like a[image]b ?

Comment: I'm not sure (and thus didn't vote to close), but I suspect this would be more appropriate for http://math.stackexchange.com/, where you probably would have to explain what the code does.

Comment: You haven't adequately characterized the desired output.

Comment: `(diff(a) >= 0) & (diff(b) >= 0)` should suffice or you want to have a function that does that, with a, b and `'>='` provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I assume that the OP wants to know the proper mathematical expression for his R code, I think this is not really an R question.

I am giving you some Latex code. Let's say `c_{ij}` denotes the elements of your `compare` matrix. Then you could use the indicator function

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function

to translate your code into a math expression

```
c_{ij}=\textbf{1}_{\left[0,\infty\right)}(a_i-a_j) \cdot \textbf{1}_{\left[0,\infty\right)}(b_i-b_j)
```

In that case, `c_{ij}` would hold `0`s and `1`s instead of `FALSE` and `TRUE`.

Comment: @Shawn88 If you like the answer you can accept it via the check box right below the vote counter.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to answer this here, since Stack Overflow doesn't support LaTeX math mode. But...

What you want is the Heaviside Step function, usually denoted with a capital Theta.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function

Theta(x) is the integral, from minus infinity to x, of the Dirac Delta function. Therefore Theta(x) = 0 for x<0, and Theta(x) = 1 for x >= 0.

You're given vectors a and b. You want matrix C. In index notation:

C_{i j} = \Theta(a_i - a_j) \times \Theta(b_i - b_j)

C becomes a matrix of ones and zeros.